# Server administration issue

Tags: linux, networking, troubleshooting

How can you troubleshoot a slow server response time? My server performance is deteriorating so fastly. I've tried fixing server software and configurations. Also checked with network connectivity. It seems there is no issue.
Could you please help me?

Comment: What server? How do you measure performance? How is it configured? As it stands it is too general to get relevant answers.

Answer (score 1):

Check CPU: `top` or `htop`

Check proceses: `ps -auxf`

Memory: `free -m`

Iops: `iotop -oPa`

Install nmon and nload

Check IO/Wait: `iostat -m 2` and `iostat -xm 2`

Tuning filesystem (noatime)

Tuning sysctl.conf

Uses: Apachebuddy

Uses: MySQLTunner

Tuning PHP

`strace`

`lsof -p`

`vmstat`

`stat`

Check hardrive: `smartmontools`

Check: `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda` and `sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sda` and `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep -i speed`

And BIOS/UEFI configuration... Uses Dell Server? Memory Operation Mode? Snoop Mode? Supermicro? Gigabyte? Quanta Server?

Network velocity in Gigabps?

Check disk velocity: `dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=64k count=16k conv=fdatasync`

RAID Monitoring?

`cat /proc/mdstat`

`cat /proc/mdstat`

`mdadm -D /dev/md1`

`mdadm -D /dev/md0`

`MAILADDR info@my-email.com`

`./mdadm --monitor --mail=root@localhost --syslog --delay=300 /dev/md0 --daemonise`

Comment: in gernally not a bad answer, but it needs supporting information, specially for the tuning part and a hint that it could break things or even in more worse conditions destroy

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add it to monitoring system like 'zabbix 'to get overviwe of it's performance ? Check CPU, Memory, Iops, Netowrk Traffic. Each one of those matrices can make your server slower.